# SQL Server Management Studio error

Tags: sql-server-2016, ssms-2016

I am getting the following error after installing SQL Server 2016 Management Studio from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx

[image: Error]

This is the error in `activityLog.xml`:

```
  <entry>
    <record>78</record>
    <time>2016/08/30 16:10:09.827</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>SetSite failed for package [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio, Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91][Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]:{   at Microsoft.SqlServer.SharedBins.InitSharedBins()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Initialize()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPackage.SetSite(IServiceProvider sp)}</description>
    <guid>{04401FF3-8B0F-4D2D-85EB-2A3542867A8B}</guid>
    <hr>80004003 - E_POINTER</hr>
    <errorinfo>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
```

I also have other versions of SQL Server 2012, SQL Server 2008 R2 on my machine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried re-install SSMS after you see this error?

Comment: Yes tried reinstalling however I get the same error. I also started getting errors on SQL Server 2012 which was working fine previously. I ended up doing System Restore to an earlier time of the day which restored my SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

You might be having compatibility issues between Visual Studio and SSMS.

If you are on Windows 10 and get a Windows Defender prompt saying something to the effect like "Unauthorized changes blocked...", then please make sure you add the executable file to the list of allowed apps. You will usually find SSMS installed at:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\ssme.exe

I believe this should take care of it - provided it is a VS-SSMS compatibility issue.